# Erosion operation (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I am trying to implement the erosion function for a binary image without using standard libraries (cv2,..). That's what I got at the moment. Is it possible to simplify my code so that there are only vector or matrix operations? Any other suggestions are also welcome.

```
mask = np.array([ 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
])

def erosion(image, mask):
    mask_size = mask.shape[0]
    left_half = int(mask_size / 2)
    right_half = int(mask_size / 2)
    if mask_size % 2 == 0:
        right_half += 1
    result = image.copy()
    # Идем по изображению
    for i in range(left_half, result.shape[0] - right_half):
        for j in range(left_half, result.shape[1] - right_half):
            left_border = int(mask_size / 2)
            mask_i = 0
            mask_j = 0
            flag = False
            right_border = left_border
            if mask_size % 2 != 0:
                right_border += 1
            # Идем по маске, перебираем каждый элемент маски
            for k in range(i - left_border, i + right_border):
                mask_j = 0
                for l in range(j - left_border, j + right_border):
                    if mask[mask_i, mask_j] == 1 and image[k, l] == 0:
                        result[i, j] = 0
                        flag = True
                        break
                    mask_j += 1
                mask_i += 1
                if(flag):
                    break
            if not (flag):
                result[i, j] = 255
    return result
```

Comment: `if mask.shape[0] % 2 != 0`  -> `if mask.shape[0] % 2`

Comment: `int(mask.shape[0] / 2)` -> `mask.shape[0] // 2`

Comment: If your code works without errors, you could ask on [codereview.se]; optimization is on topic there. Make sure to translate your Russian comments into English, though.